# collection condition filter = ((condition AND condition) OR (condition AND condition))

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter, sql

I'm stuck on something, I've look on every results I have found on Google but I haven't found the solution yet.

I'm trying to do a SQL request which look like that:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `order`.`increment_id` AS `order_increment_id`, `order`.`status` AS `order_status` FROM `magentoudropship_po` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `magentosales_flat_order` AS `order` ON main_table.order_id=order.entity_id
WHERE ((main_table.udropship_status = 0 AND main_table.created_at > '22/04/2015') OR (main_table.udropship_status = 9 AND main_table.created_at > '20/04/2015'))
```

I haven't found how to insert an AND condition inside a OR condition ...

Here's my actual code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('udpo/po')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                array('main_table.udropship_status', 'main_table.udropship_status'),
                array(array('eq' => Unirgy_DropshipPo_Model_Source::UDPO_STATUS_PENDING), array('eq' => Unirgy_DropshipPo_Model_Source::UDPO_STATUS_ACK))
            );
$collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'main_table.order_id=order.entity_id',
            array('order_increment_id' => 'increment_id', 'order_status' => 'status')
        );
$collection->load();
```

And this is the request I have for now:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `order`.`increment_id` AS `order_increment_id`,  `order`.`status` AS `order_status` FROM `magentoudropship_po` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `magentosales_flat_order` AS `order` ON  main_table.order_id=order.entity_id
WHERE ((main_table.udropship_status = 0) OR (main_table.udropship_status = 9))
```

Do you know how to achieve a condition like `((condition AND condition) OR (condition AND condition))` ?

Comment: Have you tried achieving your AND-OR condition using `Zend_Db_Select`'s methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$collection->getSelect()
->orWhere('condition1 AND condition2')
->orWhere('condition3 AND condition4')
```

Then bind the params in your conditions